# Use HTML popup in Google Apps Script to create dynamic array

Tags: html, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup

I'm trying to set up a script that will give me a popup with 6 checkboxes so i can choose which domains I want to be incorporated in an array which will be used in another script to iterate through.
I set up the script and the HTML page, but the HTML doesn't seem to be running the scripts within it. it gives the popup, but nothing comes from it.
No errors show, but nothing is logged either.

This is the script

```
function showDomainSelectionDialog() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile('PageSelectionDialog')
      .setWidth(300)
      .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Select Domains');
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
}

function processSelectedDomains(selectedDomains) {
  // Process the selected domains here
  Logger.log(selectedDomains);
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('PageSelectionDialog');
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        margin: 10px;
      }
  <body>
  </style>
    <form>
      <div class="column">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="UK"> UK</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="DE"> DE</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="FR"> FR</label>
      </div>

      <div class="button-container">
        <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="submitForm()">
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        var selectedDomains = [];
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('domain');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            selectedDomains.push(checkboxes[i].value);
          }
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        }).processSelectedDomains(selectedDomains);

        // Close the dialog
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your missing </head> tag.  Normally I like to put the style in the head so it loads before the content. I thinks it's wierd to find body tags inside of the style.  Maybe that's something new.

Comment: In your showing script, it seems that there are 2 patterns. 1. Show HTML in a dialog on Google Spreadsheet. 2. Show HTML in a browser by `doGet`. I think that the 1st situation works, and you can see the values in the log with `Logger.log(selectedDomains)`.

Comment: But, when you access Web Apps, I'm worried that when you don't log in to your Google Account, `Logger.log(selectedDomains)` doen't work. If you want to see the value of `Logger.log(selectedDomains)` with Web Apps, as a test, please log in to your Google account (it supposes that you are the owner of the script.) and test it again. By this, you can see the value in the log. But, this is just my guess. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

It's working like this for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        margin: 10px;
      }
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <form>
      <div class="column">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="UK"> UK</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="DE"> DE</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="FR"> FR</label>
      </div>

      <div class="button-container">
        <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="submitForm()">
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        var selectedDomains = [];
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('domain');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            selectedDomains.push(checkboxes[i].value);
          }
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        }).processSelectedDomains(selectedDomains);

        // Close the dialog
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Other code is the  same

Comment: my original html did have those, it still worked. the dialog box shows just fine, but i'm trying to get the script to retrieve the array in submitForm function back into the script...

Comment: Yes it did have them but they were in the wrong place

Comment: Your Logger.log worked correctly displaying the selectedDomains

Comment: it didn't come up in my execution log. where did you see it?

Comment: This `Dec 4, 2023, 5:10:50 PM Info [UK, DE, FR]` was in my execution log

Comment: I prefer to give each checkbox and id and loop through them.

Comment: i just noticed, it works in my personal gmail but not in my company workspace account, anyone have an idea why that could be the case and how i could fix it?

Comment: I'd speak with the admin of your company.